# Extract snapshots from video at a given time using video-thumb module

Tags: node.js, video, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I want to create thumbnail from a video at a certain time in node js, now I am using node module "video-thumb"

[This is the code that uses node-thumb module to create thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UToNT.png)

[And this is the result however the result is shown but don't know where the snapshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUEk.png)

Comment: I don't know where the snapshot.png file is saved.

Comment: please help or tell me the alternative for thumbnail in node js.